# Filtering dataframe on multiple columns in R with at least 6 matches

Tags: r, duplicates, filtering

I have the following data and I would like to keep only the cases that have exactly 6 instances of the same individual (same last name and first name) in the dataset.  For example, Quincy Acy appears 6 times in the df and I would like to retain each of these cases but get rid of Alex Abrines because there are only 3 instances (< 6) of that individual.

```
   last  first start_year end_year Team     GP   MIN   PTS     W     L
   <chr> <chr>      <int>    <int> <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 Abri… Alex        2016     2017 OKC      68  15.5   6      37    31
 2 Abri… Alex        2017     2018 OKC      75  15.1   4.8    42    33
 3 Abri… Alex        2018     2019 OKC      31  19     5.3    21    10
 4 Acy   Quin…       2013     2014 SAC      63  13.5   2.7    22    41
 5 Acy   Quin…       2014     2015 NYK      68  18.9   5.9    12    56
 6 Acy   Quin…       2015     2016 SAC      59  14.8   5.3    21    38
 7 Acy   Quin…       2016     2017 BKN      38  14.7   5.8    11    27
 8 Acy   Quin…       2017     2018 BKN      70  19.4   5.9    26    44
 9 Acy   Quin…       2018     2019 PHX      10  12.3   1.7     2     8
```

I have tried `x <- df %>% count(last, first) %>% filter(n == 6)` followed by `df %>% filter(last %in% x$last & first %in% x$first)` but that matches any last name and any first name separately rather than matching both last and first name.  I am sure there is also an easier solution with filter without having to use group_by first.

I would like the solution to look like:

```
  <chr> <chr>      <int>    <int> <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1 Acy   Quin…       2013     2014 SAC      63  13.5   2.7    22    41
2 Acy   Quin…       2014     2015 NYK      68  18.9   5.9    12    56
3 Acy   Quin…       2015     2016 SAC      59  14.8   5.3    21    38
4 Acy   Quin…       2016     2017 BKN      38  14.7   5.8    11    27
5 Acy   Quin…       2017     2018 BKN      70  19.4   5.9    26    44
6 Acy   Quin…       2018     2019 PHX      10  12.3   1.7     2     8
7 Adams Stev…       2013     2014 OKC      81  14.8   3.3    59    22
8 Adams Stev…       2014     2015 OKC      70  25.3   7.7    37    33
9 Adams Stev…       2015     2016 OKC      80  25.2   8      54    26
10 Adams Stev…       2016     2017 OKC      80  29.9  11.3    47    33
11 Adams Stev…       2017     2018 OKC      76  32.7  13.9    43    33
12 Adams Stev…       2018     2019 OKC      80  33.4  13.8    47    33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `count`ing to `summarise` the data, creating a new object and then do the `filter`, we can `group_by`, the 'last', 'first' and directly `filter` the groups based on the condition

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
         group_by(last, first) %>%
         filter(n() == 6)
```

If it is at least 6, then change the `==` or `>=`

---

Or another option is `table`

```
subset(df,   paste(last, first) %in% names(which(table(paste(last, first)) == 6)))
```

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  I am a new user so thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `ave` to count number of rows in each group of `first` and `last` values and select groups where number of rows is 6.

```
subset(df, ave(start_year, first, last, FUN = length) == 6)

#  last first start_year end_year Team GP  MIN PTS  W  L
#4  Acy Quin…       2013     2014  SAC 63 13.5 2.7 22 41
#5  Acy Quin…       2014     2015  NYK 68 18.9 5.9 12 56
#6  Acy Quin…       2015     2016  SAC 59 14.8 5.3 21 38
#7  Acy Quin…       2016     2017  BKN 38 14.7 5.8 11 27
#8  Acy Quin…       2017     2018  BKN 70 19.4 5.9 26 44
#9  Acy Quin…       2018     2019  PHX 10 12.3 1.7  2  8
```

We can do the same with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD[.N == 6], .(first, last)]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(last = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Abri…", "Acy"), class = "factor"), first = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Alex", "Quin…"
), class = "factor"), start_year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L), end_year = c(2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L), Team = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("BKN", "NYK", "OKC", 
"PHX", "SAC"), class = "factor"), GP = c(68L, 75L, 31L, 63L, 
68L, 59L, 38L, 70L, 10L), MIN = c(15.5, 15.1, 19, 13.5, 18.9, 
14.8, 14.7, 19.4, 12.3), PTS = c(6, 4.8, 5.3, 2.7, 5.9, 5.3, 
5.8, 5.9, 1.7), W = c(37L, 42L, 21L, 22L, 12L, 21L, 11L, 26L, 
2L), L = c(31L, 33L, 10L, 41L, 56L, 38L, 27L, 44L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```